# Set Django Rest Framework endpoint a timeout for a specific view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, request, timeout

I'm running Django 4.0.5 + Django Rest Framework + Nginx + Gunicorn
Sometimes, I'm going to need to handle some POST requests with a lot of data to process.
The user will wait for a "ok" or "fail" response and a list of ids resulting from the process.

Everything works fine so far for mid size body requests (this is subjective), but when I get into big ones, the process will take 1min+.
It's in these cases when I get a 500 error response from DRF, but my process in the background will keep running till the end (but user will not know it finished successfully).

I was doing some investigation and changed the Gunicorn timeout parameter (to 180), but didn't change the behavior in the service.

Is there a way to set a timeout larger than 60s at the @api_view or somewhere else?

Comment: Also, not sure if the timeout is from DRF or Django itself..

Answer (score 0):

Use celery async tasks to process such requests as background tasks.